# Running chessbase Reader on ubuntu

Tags: software, chessbase

I'm currently working on ubuntu, and installed wine with chessbase reader. I wanted to watch a few videos of GM Daniel King that I had. I open the folder through chessbase, but when I click on the videos, they won't work.

Have any of you experienced something similar? Could you help me out? I appreciate your help.

Comment: What did you see when it failed to work? Do you have to install some kind video decoder?

Comment: @StudentT I can open the .wmv videos but when I click on any mini clip in the page that says: 'To start a video just click on the image. The video starts automatically', it simply doesn't open a new window with the video and the board as it does on a windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

When I converted the 2014 ChessBase Database to PGN format, and finally to SCID format, I used VirtualBox (x86 and AMD64/Intel64 virtualization,  for which you need to install Windows and ChessBase) because I sure what Windows programs run perfectly with it.  However, I don't know if your hardware is powerful enough for a virtualization

Comment: Thanks, however I look for chessbase (I tried to run scidb, but it could not read chessbase files)